# Fail to upload file using FTPClient

Tags: file-upload, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I have to upload and download a file using FTP server but I am facing issues in it. Have gone though many solutions but nothing seems to be working.

I am using [secureftp-test.com](http://secureftp-test.com/) as the testing FTP server.

Below is the code for uploading where in I am using [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) storeFile method but it doesn't seems to work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String server = "ftp.secureftp-test.com";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "test";
    String pass = "test";

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {

        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        boolean login = ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        System.out.println("login " + login);
        ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        File firstLocalFile = new File("D:/jetty.pdf");

        String firstRemoteFile = "myfile.pdf";
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);

        System.out.println("Start uploading first file");
        boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        if (done) {
            System.out.println("The first file is uploaded successfully.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("upload failed");
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Each time the output is "upload failed". I don't understand where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your port is incorrect. It uses:

```
FTPS via Auth TLS/SSL and implicit FTP over SSL on port 990
```

Also, if you read the site carefully, upload is **forbidden**:

*Chilkat provides this FTPS test account for anyone wishing to test secure FTP client functionality. You may connect to ftp.secureftp-test.com, login as "test" with password "test", and download any files present on the server. The "test" account may also retrieve directory listings. **However, it is restricted from uploading files to the server.***

Reference: [secureftp-test.com](http://secureftp-test.com)

Comment: Thanks Shivan for pointing this out. Well is there any other ftp server for testing purpose which i could use just to perform a sample upload and download ?

Comment: you can setup your own FTP server, e.g. by FileZilla FTP server ( Windows ) or vsFTPd ( Linux-based )